# Вывод double через точку в Formatter

Tags: java

Код

```
formatter.format(" %d %.9f", 12, 12.22222);
```

записывает в поток число `double` через запятую. Нужно чтобы записывалось через точку (`"12.22222"`). Как это исправить?

Comment: что бы в поток записывалось число как "12.22222" а не как "12,22222"

Comment: Я думаю это настраивается как то в настройках, но не нашел в гугле.

Comment: для Scanner есть метод useLocale

Comment: Что такое `formatter`?

Comment: Экземпляр Formatter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
formatter.format(Locale.US, " %d %.9f", 12, 12.22222);
```

или

```
Formater formatter = new Formatter(Locale.US);
formatter.format(" %d %.9f",12, 12.22222);
```